# How to have span text line up

Tags: html, css, list

So I'm working on a menu, the menu is a list, with the menu titles having a different class from the menu description.

```
<ul class="menu-01">

  <li class="menu-title">CHICKEN CASHEW NUT  <span>12</span></li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">PANANG BEEF <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">GREEN CURRY CHICKEN <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">PAD PIK KING CHICKEN <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>

</ul>
```

I want the prices to line up with each other after the item title. But I'm not sure how exactly I would style it. [I'm currently just giving it a `margin-right`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ1SK.png).

Comment: Float them to the right, or position them absolute ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to `float` the price to the right:

```css
ul {
  max-width: 20em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

li span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-01">
  <li class="menu-title">CHICKEN CASHEW NUT <span>12</span>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">PANANG BEEF <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">GREEN CURRY CHICKEN <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">PAD PIK KING CHICKEN <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, such an obvious fix. Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a table like:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>CHICKEN CASHEW NUT</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">lorem ipsum</td></tr>
    <tr><td>PANANG BEEF</td><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fabian Schultz'  answer works well, here's another solution with flexbox:

It makes every `.menu-title` a flexbox container (by `display: flex`) and moves the `span` to the right by giving it `margin-left: auto`

A note: I don't know what "sn" stands for, but I suppose that should be inside the span.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none; 
  }
.menu-title {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  }
.menu-title span {
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #ccc;
  }

.menu-meal {
    margin: 0 0 12px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-01">

  <li class="menu-title">CHICKEN CASHEW NUT  <span>12</span></li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">PANANG BEEF <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">GREEN CURRY CHICKEN <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="menu-title">PAD PIK KING CHICKEN <span>12</span>sn</li>
  <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @johannes rightly said, flexbox is another way to solve this and it is my preferred route because it is much more efficient to use.

If required, read more on Flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Also, as I do not know what '*sn*' is, i have appended it to the price as you would if it were currency.

See my solution below:

**Note that:** The '*sn*' has been removed from the'*li*' tags, as they are added dynamically via CSS

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu-01">
    <li class="menu-title">CHICKEN CASHEW NUT  <span>12</span></li>
    <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="menu-title">PANANG BEEF <span>12</span></li>
    <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="menu-title">GREEN CURRY CHICKEN <span>12</span></li>
    <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
    <li class="menu-title">PAD PIK KING CHICKEN <span>12</span></li>
    <li class="menu-meal">lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* some ul styles */
ul {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 20em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

/* li display set to flex, so content flows as expected */
li {
    position: relative
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

/* 'sn' appended to the '.menu-title' span using ':after' pseudo-element */
.menu-title > span:after {
    content: "sn";
}

.menu-meal {
    font-style: italic;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
```

See demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/princebazawule/y7x66q7L/)

Hope this is helpful.